# Why do we call the variables that store the properties of an object instance variables?

Tags: java, class, oop, object, instance-variables

I'm beginning to learn more about the conceptual side of Java and with that the concept of classes, their objects, and instance variables. Although I understand that classes represent a concept, objects are an embodiment of those concepts, and instance variables are supposed to be the properties and behaviors of these concepts-- why are they specifically called instance variables? Aren't the objects the "instances" of the class?
Here's an example: consider the class Person

```
class Person {

   private int age;
   private String name;

   public Person(String userName, int userAge) {

     age = userAge;
     name = userName;
  }

}

public class Tester {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Person maya = new Person("Maya", 14);
      Person jack = new Person("Jack", 16);
   }
}
```

In this class, we have two objects, maya and jack. These two objects are instances of the class because although they belong to the same concept (a person), they hold different attributes in terms of name and age, which are reflected through the instance variables. Every person has a name and an age (its behaviors), but different variations of it.

Comment: Because the values of those variables belong to an instance.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch to clarify, are you saying that instance variables are essentially the different attributes found in objects that would cause them to become instances of the class?

Comment: Are we going for a philosophical answer? What ***other*** name would you suggest?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, I'm looking for a more abstract answer

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from Oracle's Java tutorial, at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

> Non-static fields are also known as instance variables because their values are unique to each instance of a class (to each object, in other words); the currentSpeed of one bicycle is independent from the currentSpeed of another.

Answer (score 0):

An instance variable is one that belongs to the instance: each instance gets its own version of the variable, totally independent of the other instances. You can not access an instance variable *except* through an instance.

Contrast this with a static or class variable. Such a variable belongs to the class, and is consequently shared by all instances of the class. A class variable can be accessed through either the class *or* the instance.

Comment: Don't forget the local variables, which are local to method invocations